# Porting Silverlight data access to WPF

Tags: orm, telerik, telerik-open-access, openaccess

This project write in Silverlight and used Telerik open access how to access data in WPF? how to port data access in Silverlight to WPF.

If anyone wishes to help can I upload the source.

Thank you for the help everyone.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue using the model defined in the **CRM.DataAccess** as a data layer in your application without modifying it. 
If you want to consume the data using services, you could use the [Add OpenAccess Service wizard](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/feature-ref-tools-add-service-wizard-overview.html) to generate the needed service. It will generate for you the necessary service code.

Comment: Thanks Damyan, Not solved my problem, After convert project to WPF error and not compile, If I upload a project You solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex, you need to rebuild the presentation layer of your application in order to achieve this goal. Splitting the project in 3 separate layers will allow you to have different presentation later, no matter what the technology behind is. You could have a look at the Samples Kit (http://www.telerik.com/products/orm/features/samples-kit.aspx) of the product, how to do that. 
Should you need further help, you could contact the product support.